# Terraform: command "Powershell.exe" produced invalid JSON: unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: powershell, terraform

I am trying to use Terraform's external provider to run a PowerShell script.

I am not able to pass parameters to the script from Terraform.

I am using the following code to run the script:

```
variable "file_path" {
  type        = "string"
  description = "Enter the powershell file path"
  default     = "../../Services/azurerm_iam_role/Powershell_Scripts/test.ps1"
}

data "external" "powershell_test" {
  program = ["Powershell.exe", "${var.file_path}"]

  query = {
    foo = "asdf"
    bar = "Hardcoded"
  }
}
```

The following is my PowerShell script file code:

```
# Read stdin as string
$jsonpayload = [Console]::In.ReadLine()

# Convert to JSON
$json = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonpayload

# Access JSON values
$foo = $json.foo
$bar = $json.bar
```

while executing `terraform apply` I got the following error:

> command "Powershell.exe" produced invalid JSON: unexpected end of JSON
>   input

Is there a fix or alternate solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A data source needs to output something which you don't currently appear to be doing. The [external data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html#external-program-protocol) in particular needs JSON output on `stdout` which could then be accessed under the `result` attribute of the data source.

So to continue your example PowerShell script you might want something like this (untested):

```
# Read stdin as string
$jsonpayload = [Console]::In.ReadLine()

# Convert to JSON
$json = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonpayload

# Access JSON values
$foo = $json.foo
$bar = $json.bar

# Set foobar based on foo and bar
$foobar = "$foo$bar"

# Return foo and foobar
@{
    foobar=$foobar;
    foo=$foo;
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: I would definitely use `ConvertTo-Json` instead of just writing a String to the Ouptut. It could get malformed, depending on the variables content.

Comment: @Clijsters I know basically nothing about Powershell, having avoided Windows for the last 5 years as much as possible. I had planned on using `CovertTo-Json` in the answer but had no way to test it and the online IDE at https://tio.run/# was giving me issues. If you can suggest an edit that makes the answer better than I'd be grateful.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR 

i have tried ur solution and i am getting the following error

Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:




        * data.external.powershell_test: 1 error(s) occurred:

        * data.external.powershell_test: data.external.powershell_test: command "Powershell.exe" produced invalid JSON: invalid character ',' looking for beginning of value

Comment: @ydaetskcoR PowerShell (core) is vailable on mostly any human-interactable operating system I can think of. U might want to give it a try ;) Neverthless your answer addresses the problem and is totally valid. I'll give it a small edit.

Comment: @KailashP: Please try the edited example. Some quote marks weren't escaped.